# A One-Dimensional Local Ring Admitting a Finitely Generated Reflexive Module with Finite Injective Dimension Must Be Gorenstein

Tags: commutative-algebra, finitely-generated, injective-module, gorenstein

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a one-dimensional commutative Noetherian local ring. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module with finite injective dimension $\operatorname{injdim}_R(M).$ One can prove that $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay by showing first that $\operatorname{injdim}_R(M) \geq 1$ (cf. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/232840/390180)) and subsequently appealing to the fact (proven by Bass) that $\operatorname{injdim}_R(M) = \operatorname{depth}(R)$; however, my aim is to prove the following.

> Let $(R, \mathfrak m, k)$ be a one-dimensional commutative Noetherian local ring. If $R$ admits a finitely generated reflexive $R$-module $M$ with finite injective dimension, then $R$ must be Gorenstein.

Unfortunately, I fear that the line of reasoning used to prove that $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay is of little help in proving that $R$ is Gorenstein. But at the same time, once we know that $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay, we can invoke Grothendieck's Local Duality Theorem. Ultimately, we must show that $\operatorname{Ext}_R^1(k, R) \cong k$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_R(k, R) = 0.$

**Edit:** As @metalspringpro points out, there was an unresolvable error in my initial attempt, so I have removed it. Furthermore, it suffices to prove that if $R$ admits a reflexive canonical module $\omega_R,$ then $R$ is Gorenstein.

I would greatly appreciate any advice, comments, or suggestions.

Comment: Hint: Passing to the completion if necessary, you may assume $R$ has a canonical module $\omega_R$. Then as $M$ is reflexive and as $R$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring of dimension $1$, $M$ is maximal Cohen-Macaulay. As it also has finite injective dimension, it follows that $M \cong \omega_R^{\oplus n}$ for some $n$. In particular, $\omega_R$ is reflexive. So your question reduces to why $\omega_R$ being reflexive forces $R$ to be Gorenstein in this setting.

Comment: Also, I should point out your application of the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_R(-,R)$ is not correct. If $0 \to M \to Q \to Q' \to 0$ is the injective resolution you describe, one would have an exact sequence $$0 \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(Q',R) \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(Q,R) \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R) \to \operatorname{Ext}^1_R(Q',R) \to \operatorname{Ext}^1_R(Q,R) \to \cdots$$ and one cannot conclude e.g. that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(Q,R)=0$ from injectivity of $Q$. We have $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(-,Q)=0$ when $Q$ is injective, not that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(Q,-)=0$.

Comment: @metalspringpro, your second comment is very useful. It makes sense; I had simply erroneously recalled the property that $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M, N) \cong \operatorname{Tor}_i^R(N, M)$ whenever $R$ is a commutative ring and conflated it with a property of Ext.

Comment: @metalspringpro, in fact, to show that the reflexivity of $\omega_R$ implies that $R$ is Gorenstein was my original problem; however, it was pointed out to me that the correct line of reasoning would show moreover that the existence of any finitely generated reflexive module of finite injective dimension would imply that $R$ is Gorenstein. I am still unsure how to solve the problem, but I appreciate your suggestions very much.

Comment: If you've already reduced to the case where $M=\omega_R$, then I'll add an additional hint that any reflexive module is a second syzygy, and that you should think about canonical duality.

Comment: @metalspringpro, I have filled out most of the details you have suggested, but I am not sure why it is true that $M$ is a direct sum of copies of $\omega_R.$

Comment: @metalspringpro, what are you calling "canonical duality?" I am not familiar with this.

Comment: If $R$ admits a canonical module, then any maximal Cohen-Macaulay module of finite injective dimension is isomorphic to $\omega_R^{\oplus n}$ for some $n$. A good reference for this fact as well as canonical duality as a whole is chapter 11 of "Cohen-Macaulay Representations" by Leuschke-Wiegand  (cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3766831). In particular see 11.7 there. Bruns and Herzog also has a nice chapter (Chapter 3) around this. The canonical dual of a Cohen-Macaulay $R$-module $M$ of dimension $t$ is $\operatorname{Ext}^{d-t}_R(M,\omega_R)$ where $d=\dim R$.

Comment: @metalspringpro, I have thought about this a lot, and I have written down a lot of new information regarding the canonical module and canonical duality, but I am still not seeing where to go once we have that $0 \to \omega_R \to R^m \to R^n \to M \to 0$ is a short exact sequence for some finitely generated $R$-module $M$ and some integers $m, n \geq 1.$

Comment: I have created a chat room for us [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128985/one-dimensional-local-ring-with-finite-module-of-finite-injective-dimension).